# Sort Specification of Non-Document nested Array during a $push operation

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-.net-driver

Given a document structure:

```
[{
    _id: ObjectId("someId"),
    Property: {
        CollectionProperty: [{
            ItemKey: 28,
            StringArray: [
                "ItemA",
                "ItemB"
            ]
        }]
    }
}]
```

Performing the following operation in the mongo shell does what I want:

```
db.getCollection('collection').updateOne(
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("someId"), 
    "Property.CollectionProperty.ItemKey" : 28 
}, 
{ $push : 
    { 
        "Property.CollectionProperty.$.StringArray" : { 
            $each : [ "AItemA" ], 
            $sort : 1
        }
     } 
});
```

However, I cannot find in the documentation or anywhere on the net how to reproduce THAT $sort command in C# code.  I can reproduce if it had fields by using "field":1, but not a non-document array like that.

The mongodb documentation that describes that sort is here:
[MongoDB Sort Elements that are not documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#sort-array-elements-that-are-not-documents)

Here's what I have in C# so far:

```
Builders<DataType>.Update.PushEach("Property.CollectionProperty.$.StringArray",
                new[] { "AItemA" }, null, null, ???)));
```

The ??? is what I don't know how to do... does anyone have any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: Not been an expert on  C driver, I will refrain from offering advice,
just one thing i noticed  { "_id" : ObjectId("someId") "Property.CollectionProperty.ItemKey" : 28 
}
_id is unique in each collection so you don't have to filter for both _id and  Property.xxx

Comment: @nickmilon That is what the OP is doing in their `.updateOne()` statement, which I am sure they know already works for them. All they want to know is how this translates in C#. Which is not C BTW.

Comment: @nickmilon Yes, I only posted part of the document structure -- the real collection property can have many items in it, but the ItemKey within is only unique within that particular _id... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently currently unsupported, but planned for a future release in the C# driver, as documented here:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1271